# Name me a thing prettier than freckles!

Tags: comparison

> 1. I love freckles. Just **name me a thing** prettier than freckles!

Would this be seen as a natural-looking sentence? What if we change it thus:

> 2. Just name me **any thing** prettier than freckles!
> 3. Just name me **anything** prettier than freckles!

Would these sentences equal in sense to sentence 1: "provide to me the name of a thing that is prettier than freckles"?

Or would they slide towards "change my name to a name that is prettier than *Freckles*", "start calling me a new name, the one that is prettier than *Freckles*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original #1 is quite natural,  and #2 and #3 not only do not capture the charm of the challenge "name me a thing", #2 is unnatural in the way it splits "any thing" and #3 is open to the interpretation that almost anything is prettier than freckles.

Comment: Oh, so splitting "anything" makes the sentence less natural? Interesting. I thought it might make the meaning clearer.

Comment: @CopperKettle "Any thing" *does* decrease the semantic ambiguity, but it still sounds less natural. "Any thing" suggests a concrete thing (so, not a name), so "name me any thing" *probably* isn't being used to mean "assign a name to something". On the other hand "anything" means "any possibility" which could include names. However, **"any thing" is almost universally awkward,** even when it might otherwise make a sentence clearer.

Comment: There are rare contexts where splitting "any thing" is appropriate, i.e. situations where you want to emphasize the thingness. *I don't think any thing could ever force this door open. There's not a crowbar on earth that could do it. Even a battering ram would fail. But a magic word might open it*.

Comment: I was confused by the part of your question about "Freckles" and "change my name".  "Name me" = "name (for) me". Compare:  Sing me a song.

Comment: But doesn't it mean in some cases "call me [a name]"? "Name me John."

Comment: That would be "Name me|call me *something* prettier than Freckles." or "Name me anything but Freckles".

Comment: Oh, thanks! So "Name me anything prettier than James Winterbottom" wouldn't work.

Comment: We would only use "name me..." in the sense "assign me a name" in rare contexts, e.g. actors talking with a playwright. "Can't you name me (i.e. the character I'm going to be playing) something a little less obvious than Mary Magdalene?" Usually, it's "call me" = my name is.

Comment: In #1, the challenge raised by the speaker is to name (i.e. identify, point out) something prettier than freckles. You won't be able to, because nothing's prettier than freckles!

Comment: "any thing" in many cases is almost tmesis, "Name me any [one] thing…"